# Getting a 404 when using the Nexus 7 installer PPA, how do I fix this?

Tags: installation, 13.10, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

ubuntu 13.10

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-nexus7/ubuntu-nexus7-installer
OK

```
sudo apt-get update
W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/ubuntu-nexus7-installer/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Не удалось получить http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/ubuntu-nexus7-installer/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: The PPAs don't have anything for Saucy.  That's the 404s.  You can't use those PPAs because of that.

Comment: You should be starting with **`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools`**. The ***Nexus 7 installer*** is now obsolete, and not likely to work with Ubuntu **13.10** anyway. Refer to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install